# What is ArcSDE API used for?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, api

To create applications that manipulate ArcObjects there is the VBA and Java runtimes. 
To create application that process data with ArcToolbox tools, there is ArcPy for Python.

Today, I discovered that there is a C and Java APIs for ArcSDE! What are ArcSDE APIs for? Do they provide exactly the same functionalities as ArcSDE command lines?

Are there any other ArcGIS API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ArcSDE APIs date from the earliest days of ArcSDE. It was how you interacted with the data stored in a RDBMS. This was before there were ArcToolbox tools or many ArcObjects classes and methods. Because of this, the ArcSDE APIs have almost no support for geodatabase objects beyond points,lines,polygons--no feature datasets, network datasets, etc.

The APIs are being deprecated and no longer released because there are other ways to interact with ArcSDE data now--they're just geodatabase data like any other type of storage. Details on page 3 of this [10.1 and 10.2 deprecation document](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/W26496_W25918_DEPRECATION_PLAN_FOR_ARCGIS_101_and_102_FINAL_050713.pdf) (pdf file).